# Ember.js: how to pass model to a template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm testing Ember.js and I have a very trivial problem. 
I want to show in Handlebars Template an input text with the value of a variable called **'test'** with value *'This is a test'*

**The problem is that input is empty as well as h1 element although the varibale has a value**

This is file ***routes/index.js***

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model : function(){
        return { test:'This is a test'}
    },

    /* Default Implementation */
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model);
    }

});
```

This is file ***templates/index.hbs***

```
{{input value=test type="text" }}

<h1>  {{test}} </h1>
```

This is file ***router.js***

```
Router.map(function() 
  this.route('index', { path: '/' });
});
```

Where is the error?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

```
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('test', model);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now!

Comment: This is terrible, there are a million ways to do it and you chose the worst one. You can just access it with `model.test` you can use `Ember.computed.alias/oneWay/reads`. The problem with what you are doing at the moment is that you don't `return this._super(...arguments)` which is responsible of setting the model to the model property of the controller.

Comment: You should also include an explanation on how this piece of code helps the OP.

Comment: I changed the way to access in view usign "model.test", in this way I can drop controller

Answer (score -1):

```
{{input value=model.test type="text" }}

<h1>  {{model.test}} </h1>
```

And no need to implement setupController